# Looping lists of lists to count the appearance of each pair of elements (in son lists)

Tags: python, performance, loops

Two lists of lists as below, and it needs to find out how many times (count) the pair of each elements in the son lists.

For example, William_Delta appear 4 times.

The result is to be written into a txt file.

```
processes = [['Iota', 'Gamma', 'Kappa'], ['Delta', 'Zeta', 'Beta'], ['Alpha', 'Zeta'], ['Alpha', 'Epsilon', 'Delta', 'Beta']]
staffs = [['William', 'James', 'Noah', 'Oliver'], ['Benjamin', 'Oliver', 'William'],['Oliver', 'Benjamin']]


list_output = []

for each_p in processes:
    for p in each_p:
        for each_s in staffs:
            for s in each_s:
                output = s + '_' + p
                list_output.append(output)

uniques = set(list_output)

with open('c:\\temp\\outfile.txt', 'a') as outfile:

  for ox in uniques:
    outfile.write(ox + '@' + str(list_output.count(ox)) + "\n")
```

The lengths of both 'processes' and 'staffs' are very long so it takes much time to complete.

What's the better way to make the run shorter?

Comment: Are the elements in each sublist unique? For example can you have ['William', 'William', 'Noah', 'Oliver'] in a sub-list (notice the two William)?

Comment: @DaniMesejo, thank you for the comment. Yes, the elements in each sublist is unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count each time an element appears in each sublist, then use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to find all the pairs. In the end the total count is the multiplication of each count.
For example, `"William"` appears 2 times and `"Delta"` appears 2 times, therefore total count of the pair `"William_Delta"` is 4 (2 * 2).

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import product

processes = [['Iota', 'Gamma', 'Kappa'], ['Delta', 'Zeta', 'Beta'], ['Alpha', 'Zeta'], ['Alpha', 'Epsilon', 'Delta', 'Beta']]
staffs = [['William', 'James', 'Noah', 'Oliver'], ['Benjamin', 'Oliver', 'William'],['Oliver', 'Benjamin']]


count_staffs = Counter(st for staff in staffs for st in staff)
count_processes = Counter(pr for process in processes for pr in process)

with open('outfile.txt', 'a') as outfile:
    for (staff, cs), (process, cp) in product(count_staffs.items(), count_processes.items()):
        outfile.write(f"{staff}_{process}@{cs * cp}\n")
```

This solution should be faster than finding all the pairs and counting them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) and [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) from [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import product, chain

output = Counter(
    f"{s}_{p}" for p, s in 
    product(*map(chain.from_iterable, [processes, staffs]))
)

with open(file) as outfile:
    for name, count in output.items():
        outfile.write(f"{name}@{count}\n")
```

A little more verbose version would be:

```
all_processes = chain.from_iterable(processes)
all_staffs = chain.from_iterable(staffs)

name_counts = Counter(f"{s}_{p}" for s, p in product(all_processes, all_staffs))

with open(file) as outfile:
    for name, count in name_counts.items():
        outfile.write(f"{name}@{count}\n")
```

Comment: thank you for your help! hope you don't mind I chose another for the answer! :)